# Scroll to ID after loading images in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, dom, scroll

I have a react app, which renders the data on the screen. The URL is of the format `<DOMAIN>/slug#entityId`. Thus, after the view is loaded, I need to scroll to that specific `#entityId` provided as the `id` of the HTML element.
I am using React's `componentDidUpdate()` method to scroll to the ID after the render occurs.

```js
componentDidUpdate () {
  if(// data rendered into view) {
    const id = this.entityId;

    if (id) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById(id);

        if (element) {
          element.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }
      }, 500);
    }
  } 
}
```

Thus, the scroll to the ID happens before the images are loaded. This leads to the scroll not stopping at the expected place. The number of images is their resolution is variable.
Increasing the timeout to 1000ms does solve the issue. But is this an optimal solution?

Answer (score -1):

with document ready

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if(// data rendered into view) {
        const id = this.entityId;
    
        if (id) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            const element = document.getElementById(id);
    
            if (element) {
              element.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
              });
            }
          }, 500);
        }
      } 
    }
    });
```